# Does there exist a regular language that's not Turing Recognizable?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, computation-theory, turing-machines

Is it possible for a regular language to be non-Turing Recognizable?

Comment: Sounds like a *much* better question for [cs.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope! If you have a regular language, you can get a DFA for it, then convert that DFA into a Turing machine by slightly adjusting the transitions so that they mechanically move the tape head forward. As a result, that language is also Turing-recognizable.